# MCMC with missing data

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, missing-data

I want to perform some parameter inference on a dataset. In particular, I have some data $y$, with which I want do find posterior distributions for the parameters $\theta$. I have a Metropolis Hastings scheme that works with a complete simulated dataset. I have now generated a similar dataset, but have made it so some of the values are missing (chosen randomly). Each datapoint is actually a vector that consists of about 8 components. Some of the components are always present for each vector. Data is deemed as missing if components 1,3 and 5 don't sum to component 7, and if components 2,4 and 6 don't sum to component 8. I don't know which components (or whether it's both) are the ones with missing data though.

What's the best way for me to account for this missing data? I have tried summing over all possible states, and this gets me sort of in the right region, but still not that close to the simulated parameter values I used. If I restrict to just the data vectors where I have complete information, I don't have many datapoints.

When reading the literature, I've been struggling with how to convert my data into the form $Y=(y_1,y_2,...,y_n)$ where some of the $y_i$ are missing. If anyone could help with this (or give suggestions on dealing with missing data in this situation), it would be much appreciated.

Edit: To make things a bit clearer, for my data I essentially have an $8 \times N$ matrix where $N$ is the number of observations.

In rows where I don't have complete information (only applies to about half of the columns, but most of the rows), I have a lower and upper bound for each piece of missing data, as well as a constraint on their sum. If I include the missing data as something I want to infer from the MCMC scheme, how can I include this information?

Comment: Quite simply: put a prior on it. Sample from the posterior for the missing data. This is why MICE is called the "Approximate Bayesian Bootstrap".

Comment: @AdamO So I essentially have an 8xN matrix, where N is the number of samples I have. For some of the columns, I don't know what the value is, but I know it is at least some value $n_i$, and at most some value $k_i$ (and these values can be different for each row). How can I incorporate this?

Comment: You will probably need expert on-hands statistical assistance to complete an imputed analysis. The "easy" approach is to exclude incomplete cases. Your data description isn't right: we have $N$ *rows* for each observation, and 8 variables/columns. A complete case analysis excludes any row with missing data.

Comment: @AdamO Unfortunately excluding incomplete rows doesn't work very well due to the small amount of data remaining if I do that.

Ah, sorry. Each row corresponds to a unit, with each column in effect describing a component of that unit. So a complete version of my dataset would fully describe the make up of each unit in my dataset (it's all at a single point in time, which is fine as I'm fitting the model at steady state).

What do you mean by on-hands statistical assistance?

Comment: You have $p=8$ features. How many rows of data are complete?

Comment: @AdamO Okay, yeah. Though the features aren't independent, due to the last two columns essentially being linear combinations of previous columns (if they were complete). Maybe 5% of them are complete. I've tried inferring the parameters using just the complete rows, but I get closer estimates marginalising over the missing data (though they still aren't very close).